# While Splitting CLOB data by delimiter facing issue

Tags: regex, oracle, blob, clob

I am trying to convert blob data to clob by using the below function, it is working fine. but after converting it to CLOB i want to split the records based on the delimiter which isn't working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blob_to_clob (blob_in IN BLOB)
  RETURN CLOB
AS
     c_buffer  CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
     v_clob    CLOB;
     v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_start   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);

  FOR i IN 1 .. CEIL( DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / c_buffer ) LOOP
    v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in, c_buffer, v_start));
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);
    v_start := v_start + c_buffer;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN v_clob;
END blob_to_clob;
/
```

below is the sample CLOB data it shows delimiter as '?'
**query**

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(XMLRECORD) from FMKC_STMT_PRINTED where recid = '0225307596-20180923';
```

**Output**
181390444268592.000001?181403657657150.120001?181576596572996.090001?181586235750048.110001?182271815726104.190001?182274070050018.050001?182294213659098.050001

But when i tried to run below query to fetch only 1st value it is not able to split it based upon '?'

select REGEXP_SUBSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(XMLRECORD), '[^?"]+', 1, 1) from FMKC_STMT_PRINTED where recid = '0225307596-20180923';

I even tried below function to split the CLOB data

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_clob(
  i_str    IN  CLOB,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist /* or cloblist */ DETERMINISTIC PIPELINED
AS
  p_start        PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  p_end          PLS_INTEGER;
  c_len CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      PIPE ROW ( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( i_str, p_end - p_start, p_start ) );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      PIPE ROW ( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( i_str, c_len - p_start + 1, p_start ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

but still the result is same it shows me '?' delimiter but when using it in the query

SELECT split_clob( blob_to_clob(XMLRECORD), '?' ) AS RECID
FROM   KES_STMT_PRINT_TEST t;

It is not working

**Output**
181390444268592.000001?181403657657150.120001?181576596572996.090001

Expected Output is 
181390444268592.000001
181403657657150.120001
181576596572996.090001

Comment: That question mark may instead be a unicode character that your program can't display properly. It's highly suspect to see a question mark as a delimiter in a string. From the way you worded your question, it sounds like you don't control what goes into the original CLOB data. Can you ask someone who put the data into the CLOB field?

Comment: I assume (just by the name of the function) that `CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` casts to `VARCHAR2` and not to `CLOB`? The distinction is important. If it is indeed `VARCHAR2`, you can wrap the return value within `DUMP()` and inspect the characters after conversion to `VARCHAR2` - for example, to confirm that what you are seeing are indeed question marks, as opposed to something else.

Comment: thanks for the replies. Updated my question my original data is in blob type, but i need to extract values from it which isn't possible directly from blob type so using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 function to convert it VARCHAR2 or even used this function to convert it to CLOB. then using slpit clob function and mentioning delimiter will extract the values from it. but the delimiter doesn't seems to be '?' which it shows indeed. that is where i am stuck.

Comment: I'd suggest using dbms_lob.converttoclob instead of your version. There may be some charset subtleties involved. Are you sure the "?" in your CLOB actually *is* a question mark character?